# How to select all and clear items/cells in UIButton action method

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a `UICollectionView` and I try to select all or clear all item/cell after a `UIButton` is tapped.

How can I do that like picture?

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to manage one array for selection or you if you are using model then you can add one more field for selection property.

```
@IBAction func selectAll(_ sender: UIButton) {
  // Set Whole Array to 1 and reload collection view.
}

@IBAction func clearAll(_ sender: UIButton) {
  //Set Whole array to 0 and reload collection View
}


// In collectionView method Check selection condition and Display Check mark.
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // If Array value is 1 at indexPath.row then set Checked view otherwise Unchecked view.
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. that slove the problem for me.